# How to Handle Timed Out Error Message in Bash Script for Vagrant Up Command

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, while-loop, vagrant

So I have a init script in which I am trying to handle some errors that pop-up and/or occur when a vagrant machine is trying to come up.

`init.sh` Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Timeout Error for SSH on Vagrantfile
TIMEOUT=$(echo "Timed out")

# Node Variables 
MASTER=$(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-k8s-master
NODE_1=$(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-node-1
NODE_2=$(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-node-2

# Initialize Cluster
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to initialize the cluster in $pwd (yes/no)?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) vagrant up; \
        if (($TIMEOUT));
            then vagrant destroy $MASTER -f;
                vagrant up $MASTER --[no-]destroy-on-error;
        elif (($TIMEOUT));
            then vagrant destroy $NODE_1 -f;
                vagrant up $NODE_1 --[no-]destroy-on-error;
        elif (($TIMEOUT));
            then vagrant destroy $NODE_2 -f;
                vagrant up $NODE_2 --[no-]destroy-on-error;
        else (($TIMEOUT=FALSE));
            echo "Node Provisioned";
        fi
        break;; \
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

# Prepare Join Command
vagrant ssh -c "kubeadm token create --print-join-command > /tmp/temp_join_token.txt; \
        cat /tmp/temp_join_token.txt; \
        exit" \
$(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-k8s-master

# Copy the file within Directory opn Local Host
vagrant scp $(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-k8s-master:/tmp/temp_join_token.txt .

# Copy the File to Guest Machines
vagrant scp $(pwd)/temp_join_token.txt $(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-node-1:/home/vagrant
vagrant scp $(pwd)/temp_join_token.txt $(pwd | awk -F/ '{print $5}')-node-2:/home/vagrant

# Delete Token on Local host
rm $(pwd)/temp_join_token.txt

# Echo Completion
echo "Cluster has been initialized and Join Command is inside the worker nodes on home directory"
```

The basic premise of the script is just to `vagrant up` on a machine within a particular directory. I have an interactive prompt to prompt the user for a yes or no to "provision a cluster" from the Vagrantfile in that directory. However, when in that directory and `vagrant up` is initialized, sometimes I will get an error message as such:

```
Timed out...
```

The message is rather long, so I just put the first two words that come up, but it's due to SSH not being provisioned on the machine. However, I have a solution:

1. If vagrant up encounters the timeout message for Master node: destroy the machine that failed

```
vagrant destroy $MASTER -f
```

2. If vagrant up encounters the timeout message for Node-1 worker node destroy the machine that failed:

```
vagrant destroy $NODE_1 -f
```

3. If vagrant up encounters the timeout message for Node-2 worker node destroy the machine that failed:

```
vagrant destroy $NODE_2 -f
```

I know my while loop syntax for the prompt works, but the main focus is creating a conditional for-loop for those three nodes, that if it fails due to a $TIMEOUT, destroy it and bring it back up again until it gets provisioned.

Can I get some help?
Perhaps my if-then statement approach in the while loop is wrong, not really sure.
I also know my syntax is wrong, so I welcome any and all approaches.
The timeout message looks like this:
[image]

Just an update here, but when I run the script I get the following error messages:

```
sto@suplab02:~/Engineering-Labs/jcarpentier/Kubernetes$ ./init.sh
Do you wish to initialize the cluster in  (yes/no)?yes
Bringing machine 'jcarpentier-k8s-master' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'jcarpentier-node-1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'jcarpentier-node-2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' version '202008.16.0' is up to date...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Setting the name of the VM: Kubernetes_jcarpentier-k8s-master_1598286213993_42402
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2212.
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Vagrant has detected a configuration issue which exposes a
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: vulnerability with the installed version of VirtualBox. The
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: current guest is configured to use an E1000 NIC type for a
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: network adapter which is vulnerable in this version of VirtualBox.
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Ensure the guest is trusted to use this configuration or update
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: the NIC type using one of the methods below:
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master:
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master:   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html#default-nic-type
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master:   https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html#virtualbox-nic-type
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    jcarpentier-k8s-master: Adapter 1: nat
    jcarpentier-k8s-master: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Forwarding ports...
    jcarpentier-k8s-master: 22 (guest) => 2212 (host) (adapter 1)
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Booting VM...
==> jcarpentier-k8s-master: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    jcarpentier-k8s-master: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2212
    jcarpentier-k8s-master: SSH username: vagrant
    jcarpentier-k8s-master: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
./init.sh: line 14: ((: Timed out: syntax error in expression (error token is "out")
./init.sh: line 17: ((: Timed out: syntax error in expression (error token is "out")
./init.sh: line 20: ((: Timed out: syntax error in expression (error token is "out")
./init.sh: line 23: ((: Timed out=FALSE: syntax error in expression (error token is "out=FALSE")
Node Provisioned
```

It looks like my issue is with the if then statement, any advice:

```
                if (($TIMEOUT));
                        then vagrant destroy $MASTER -f;
                                vagrant up $MASTER --[no-]destroy-on-error;
                elif (($TIMEOUT));
                        then vagrant destroy $NODE_1 -f;
                                vagrant up $NODE_1 --[no-]destroy-on-error;
                elif (($TIMEOUT));
                        then vagrant destroy $NODE_2 -f;
                                vagrant up $NODE_2 --[no-]destroy-on-error;
                else (($TIMEOUT=FALSE));
                        echo "Node Provisioned";
                fi
```

Comment: So I set the $TIMEOUT values to $TIMEOUT=TRUE to see if that would work.

Comment: It looks like that didn't help

Comment: ./init.sh: line 14: ((: Timed out=TRUE: syntax error in expression (error token is "out=TRUE")
./init.sh: line 17: ((: Timed out=TRUE: syntax error in expression (error token is "out=TRUE")
./init.sh: line 20: ((: Timed out=TRUE: syntax error in expression (error token is "out=TRUE")
./init.sh: line 23: ((: Timed out=FALSE: syntax error in expression (error token is "out=FALSE")
Node Provisioned